How i can publish my Nextjs web project from VS code to Azure web portal?
Next.js App Deployment to Azure Web App Succeeds but Changes Not Reflected on Live Site
I'm working on a Next.js project, and I'm deploying it to an Azure Web App using Visual Studio Code. Here’s the process I followed:
Build the Project: I ran the following command in my project root to create the .next folder:
npm run build
This successfully generates the .next folder in my project.
Deploy to Web App:
In Visual Studio Code, I right-clicked on the .next folder and selected Deploy to Web App.
After selecting my target Web App, I saw a status message in the Azure section of Visual Studio Code: "Deployed to App 'xyz-web-name' Succeeded".
Issue: When I navigate to my website (https://xyz-web-name.azurewebsites.net) in a browser, I do not see the changes I made in the latest deployment. The site still shows the previous version.
Additional Details:
The Web App name in Azure is xyz-web-name.
The deployment seems to complete successfully as indicated by the status message in VS Code.
The .next folder is created after running npm run build without any errors.
I'm not sure if I'm missing a step after deploying or if there's a caching issue.
My Questions:
Is there an additional step I need to perform after deploying the .next folder to ensure the latest changes are visible on the live site?
Could this be a caching issue on Azure, or do I need to restart the Web App after deploying?
What is the ideal process for deploying a Next.js app from Visual Studio Code to Azure to ensure that changes are reflected correctly?
Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Are you following any doc?

@ManthanVaja, Check if below answer helps.

Restart the site to pick up the changes in the App Service.
Verify if the changes are properly deployed to Azure App Service.
Navigate to Kudu (the advanced too) and inspect the contents of the deployed app and check if the changes are reflecting.

Delete the .next folder locally.
Run npm run dev again to regenerate the build.



Redeploy to Azure App Service using Visual Studio Code.
Clear the browser cache and reload the page.

I have created a NextJs Project and deployed to Azure App Service(Node 20LTS)
Package.json:
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  }

Deployed modified/updated project to Azure.
Initially, couldn't see the changes reflecting when I click on Browse Site after deploying the app to Azure.


Could see the changes reflecting in the Site after refreshing the site:


